# C++, Interest Calculator not displaying correct output

Tags: c++

The question asks "Write a program that reads an initial investment balance and an interest rate, then prints the number of years it takes for the investment to reach one million dollars."

- *The inputs I've been putting in are 100 for amount, and 3 for interest rate. But when i compile and run, the output is 29 which is incorrect as the amount is only 187 which isn't at all close to a million.*

```
/*
Question: Write a program that reads an initial
investment balance and an interest rate, then 
prints the number of years it takes for the 
investment to reach one million dollars.
*/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Obtain user amount
    double amount;
    cout << "Please enter an initial investment balance ($0.00): $";
    cin >> amount;

    //Obtain user interest rate
    double interest_rate;
    cout << "Please enter an interest rate: ";
    cin >> interest_rate;

    //Convert interest rate to decimal
    interest_rate = interest_rate / 100;
    int time = 1;

    //Calculate how many years
    while (amount < 1000000)
    {
        amount = amount * (1 + (interest_rate * time));
        ++time;
    }
    
    //Display years
    cout << "Years to reach one million: " << time;
    return 0;
}
```

The output i am expecting is:

### "Years to reach one million: 333300"

since 333300 is exactly one million.

Comment: "since 333300 is exactly one million." ?can you explain?

Comment: They perhaps mean it would take 333300 years to reach the 1M mark. As answered, the computing is not correct and hence, the error comes.

Comment: You could have discovered the bug yourself by printing out the running value for two years on an account at 10%.

Comment: In the loop, multiply `amount` by `(1 + interest_rate)`, not `(1 + (interest_rate*time))`.    By doing the latter, you're effectively increasing the interest rate on every iteration.

Comment: @Peter: OP is also multiplying by `amount` on each step.

Comment: Note that you reach $1M much sooner than you think at 3% assuming annual compounding. If the interest is not reinvested then yes, it's around 333,300 years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In one year, the amount will grow to

```
amount * (1 + interest_rate)
```

and in two years, the amount grows to

```
amount * (1 + interest_rate) * (1 + interest_rate)
```

assuming annual compounding of your interest rate. Your inclusion of `time`, and the continuous multiplication by `amount` are errors.

Note that there is a closed form solution. For rate *r*, initial amount *I*, final amount *A*, the number of years *t* is

> *t* = ln(*A* / *I*) / ln(1 + *r*)

which you need to round up.